# How do I fix this Facebook Messenger Code Error

Tags: html, facebook, share, messenger

`I have found this code on stackoverflow (here). It works. This code let me share from web to facebook messenger directly.
But I found an error.
I can share my website while accessing brower and facebook post.
But if I open my website from messenger and access my site, I can't share it anymore.
Messenger Pop up and instantly goes down.

So, it only works when I share my site while accessing browser and facebook post.
When I access my site from messenger and try to share, it fail....

Share

```html
<a href="fb-messenger://share/?link=http://url-you-want-to-share.com&app_id=your-app-id-here">Share</a>
```

Thanks for your time.